# How to create dynamic table from JSON values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to create dynamic table using jquery.
the problem is the key values are dynamic.

```
combination_sizetype =  Array ( [0] => 20FR 
            [1] => 20GP 
            [2] => 20HC 
            [3] => 20HD 
            [4] => 20OT 
            [5] => 20RH 
            [6] => 40FR 
            [7] => 40GP 
            [8] => 40HC 
            [9] => 40HD 
            [10] => 40OT 
            [11] => 40RH 
            [12] => 45FR 
            [13] => 45GP 
            [14] => 45HC 
            [15] => 45HD 
            [16] => 45OT 
            [17] => 45RH 
             )
```

and then i have json like this

```
  out_json = [
    {
    "20FR":"0",
    "20GP":"1",
    "20HC":"0",
    "20HD":"0",
    "20OT":"0",
    "20RH":"2",
    "40FR":"0",
    "40GP":"2",
    "40HC":"0",
    "40HD":"0",
    "40OT":"0",
    "40RH":"1",
    "45FR":"0",
    "45GP":"0",
    "45HC":"0",
    "45HD":"0",
    "45OT":"0",
    "45RH":"0",
    "location":"CHENNAI"
    },{"20FR":"0","20GP":"1","20HC":"0","20HD":"0","20OT":"0","20RH":"0","40FR":"0","40GP":"5","40HC":"0","40HD":"0","40OT":"0","40RH":"0","45FR":"0","45GP":"1","45HC":"0","45HD":"0","45OT":"0","45RH":"0","location":"COLOMBO"},{"20FR":"0","20GP":"5","20HC":"0","20HD":"0","20OT":"0","20RH":"0","40FR":"0","40GP":"1","40HC":"0","40HD":"0","40OT":"0","40RH":"0","45FR":"0","45GP":"0","45HC":"0","45HD":"0","45OT":"0","45RH":"0","location":"DELHI"},{"20FR":"0","20GP":"0","20HC":"0","20HD":"0","20OT":"0","20RH":"0","40FR":"0","40GP":"5","40HC":"0","40HD":"0","40OT":"0","40RH":"0","45FR":"0","45GP":"0","45HC":"0","45HD":"0","45OT":"0","45RH":"0","location":"PORT KLANG"},{"20FR":"2","20GP":"0","20HC":"0","20HD":"0","20OT":"0","20RH":"0","40FR":"0","40GP":"2","40HC":"0","40HD":"0","40OT":"0","40RH":"0","45FR":"0","45GP":"0","45HC":"0","45HD":"0","45OT":"0","45RH":"0","location":"ROTTERDAM"}]
```

now i need to create table like this

```
    ---------------------------
   location | 20FR| 20GP|20HC .....ETC..,|  <th>  <-- combination_sizetype array
    ---------------------------
    chennai  |  0  |  1  |  0 .....ETC., .| <tr><td></td>...</tr>    <-- this rows have to assign from json by using combination_sizetype array
     ....,
    ...,
    ... ,,,
    -----------
```

Please some one help or please give me logic to make this table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this,

```js
var out_json = [{
  "20FR": "0",
  "20GP": "1",
  "20HC": "0",
  "20HD": "0",
  "20OT": "0",
  "20RH": "2",
  "40FR": "0",
  "40GP": "2",
  "40HC": "0",
  "40HD": "0",
  "40OT": "0",
  "40RH": "1",
  "45FR": "0",
  "45GP": "0",
  "45HC": "0",
  "45HD": "0",
  "45OT": "0",
  "45RH": "0",
  "location": "CHENNAI"
}, {
  "20FR": "0",
  "20GP": "1",
  "20HC": "0",
  "20HD": "0",
  "20OT": "0",
  "20RH": "0",
  "40FR": "0",
  "40GP": "5",
  "40HC": "0",
  "40HD": "0",
  "40OT": "0",
  "40RH": "0",
  "45FR": "0",
  "45GP": "1",
  "45HC": "0",
  "45HD": "0",
  "45OT": "0",
  "45RH": "0",
  "location": "COLOMBO"
}, {
  "20FR": "0",
  "20GP": "5",
  "20HC": "0",
  "20HD": "0",
  "20OT": "0",
  "20RH": "0",
  "40FR": "0",
  "40GP": "1",
  "40HC": "0",
  "40HD": "0",
  "40OT": "0",
  "40RH": "0",
  "45FR": "0",
  "45GP": "0",
  "45HC": "0",
  "45HD": "0",
  "45OT": "0",
  "45RH": "0",
  "location": "DELHI"
}, {
  "20FR": "0",
  "20GP": "0",
  "20HC": "0",
  "20HD": "0",
  "20OT": "0",
  "20RH": "0",
  "40FR": "0",
  "40GP": "5",
  "40HC": "0",
  "40HD": "0",
  "40OT": "0",
  "40RH": "0",
  "45FR": "0",
  "45GP": "0",
  "45HC": "0",
  "45HD": "0",
  "45OT": "0",
  "45RH": "0",
  "location": "PORT KLANG"
}, {
  "20FR": "2",
  "20GP": "0",
  "20HC": "0",
  "20HD": "0",
  "20OT": "0",
  "20RH": "0",
  "40FR": "0",
  "40GP": "2",
  "40HC": "0",
  "40HD": "0",
  "40OT": "0",
  "40RH": "0",
  "45FR": "0",
  "45GP": "0",
  "45HC": "0",
  "45HD": "0",
  "45OT": "0",
  "45RH": "0",
  "location": "ROTTERDAM"
}];


out_json.forEach(function(v, i) {
  console.log(v);
  var row = '<tr>',
    td1 = '',
    td2 = '';
  jQuery.each(v, function(ind, val) {
    if (i == 0)
      td1 += '<th>' + ind + '</th>';
    td2 += '<td>' + val + '</td>';
  });
  if (i == 0)
    row += td1 + '</tr>'
  row += '<tr>' + td2 + '</tr>';
  $('table').append(row);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

> HTML :

```
<table id="ooo" class="table table-bordered">
        </table>
```

> Jquery :

```
<script type="text/javascript">


  out_json = [
        {
            "20FR": "0",
            "20GP": "1",
            "20HC": "0",
            "20HD": "0",
            "20OT": "0",
            "20RH": "2",
            "40FR": "0",
            "40GP": "2",
            "40HC": "0",
            "40HD": "0",
            "40OT": "0",
            "40RH": "1",
            "45FR": "0",
            "45GP": "0",
            "45HC": "0",
            "45HD": "0",
            "45OT": "0",
            "45RH": "0",
            "location": "CHENNAI"
        }, {"20FR": "0", "20GP": "1", "20HC": "0", "20HD": "0", "20OT": "0", "20RH": "0", "40FR": "0", "40GP": "5", "40HC": "0", "40HD": "0", "40OT": "0", "40RH": "0", "45FR": "0", "45GP": "1", "45HC": "0", "45HD": "0", "45OT": "0", "45RH": "0", "location": "COLOMBO"}, {"20FR": "0", "20GP": "5", "20HC": "0", "20HD": "0", "20OT": "0", "20RH": "0", "40FR": "0", "40GP": "1", "40HC": "0", "40HD": "0", "40OT": "0", "40RH": "0", "45FR": "0", "45GP": "0", "45HC": "0", "45HD": "0", "45OT": "0", "45RH": "0", "location": "DELHI"}, {"20FR": "0", "20GP": "0", "20HC": "0", "20HD": "0", "20OT": "0", "20RH": "0", "40FR": "0", "40GP": "5", "40HC": "0", "40HD": "0", "40OT": "0", "40RH": "0", "45FR": "0", "45GP": "0", "45HC": "0", "45HD": "0", "45OT": "0", "45RH": "0", "location": "PORT KLANG"}, {"20FR": "2", "20GP": "0", "20HC": "0", "20HD": "0", "20OT": "0", "20RH": "0", "40FR": "0", "40GP": "2", "40HC": "0", "40HD": "0", "40OT": "0", "40RH": "0", "45FR": "0", "45GP": "0", "45HC": "0", "45HD": "0", "45OT": "0", "45RH": "0", "location": "ROTTERDAM"}];


     $.each(out_json, function (m, n) {
      var xx, yy = "";
      var row = '<tr>';
        $.each(n, function (a, b) {
          xx += "<td>" + a + "</td>";
          yy += "<td>" + b + "</td>";
       });
      row += xx + '</tr><tr>' + yy + '</tr>';
      $('#ooo').append(row)
   });



$('#ooo tr td:nth-last-child(1)').each(function () {
        var thisv = $(this);
        $(this).closest('tr').prepend(thisv)
        console.log($(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(1)'))
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

To get proper table check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1kxvm45r/) or this snippet:

```js
 out_json = [{
   "20FR": "0",
   "20GP": "1",
   "20HC": "0",
   "20HD": "0",
   "20OT": "0",
   "20RH": "2",
   "40FR": "0",
   "40GP": "2",
   "40HC": "0",
   "40HD": "0",
   "40OT": "0",
   "40RH": "1",
   "45FR": "0",
   "45GP": "0",
   "45HC": "0",
   "45HD": "0",
   "45OT": "0",
   "45RH": "0",
   "location": "CHENNAI"
 }, {
   "20FR": "0",
   "20GP": "1",
   "20HC": "0",
   "20HD": "0",
   "20OT": "0",
   "20RH": "0",
   "40FR": "0",
   "40GP": "5",
   "40HC": "0",
   "40HD": "0",
   "40OT": "0",
   "40RH": "0",
   "45FR": "0",
   "45GP": "1",
   "45HC": "0",
   "45HD": "0",
   "45OT": "0",
   "45RH": "0",
   "location": "COLOMBO"
 }, {
   "20FR": "0",
   "20GP": "5",
   "20HC": "0",
   "20HD": "0",
   "20OT": "0",
   "20RH": "0",
   "40FR": "0",
   "40GP": "1",
   "40HC": "0",
   "40HD": "0",
   "40OT": "0",
   "40RH": "0",
   "45FR": "0",
   "45GP": "0",
   "45HC": "0",
   "45HD": "0",
   "45OT": "0",
   "45RH": "0",
   "location": "DELHI"
 }, {
   "20FR": "0",
   "20GP": "0",
   "20HC": "0",
   "20HD": "0",
   "20OT": "0",
   "20RH": "0",
   "40FR": "0",
   "40GP": "5",
   "40HC": "0",
   "40HD": "0",
   "40OT": "0",
   "40RH": "0",
   "45FR": "0",
   "45GP": "0",
   "45HC": "0",
   "45HD": "0",
   "45OT": "0",
   "45RH": "0",
   "location": "PORT KLANG"
 }, {
   "20FR": "2",
   "20GP": "0",
   "20HC": "0",
   "20HD": "0",
   "20OT": "0",
   "20RH": "0",
   "40FR": "0",
   "40GP": "2",
   "40HC": "0",
   "40HD": "0",
   "40OT": "0",
   "40RH": "0",
   "45FR": "0",
   "45GP": "0",
   "45HC": "0",
   "45HD": "0",
   "45OT": "0",
   "45RH": "0",
   "location": "ROTTERDAM"
 }]
 var v = $("#data").detach()   // detach the element as dom is slow
 var str = ""
 str = "<tr>"
 $.each(out_json[0], function(key, valu) {

   str = str + "<th>" + key + "</th>"
 })
 str = str + "</tr>"
 $.each(out_json, function(index, value) {
   str = str + "<tr>"
   $.each(value, function(key, valu) {
     str = str + "<td>" + valu + "</td>"
   })

   str = str + "</tr>"
 })
 v.html(str)
 $("body").append(v)   // append element to the parent, in case example body
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="data"></table>
```